# Storing API Keys in react-native app with expo library

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, express

I have a question, please, if possible explain in simple terms. Im new to react native, what's the best way to store API keys in a secure way where they can't reverse engineer it and get the keys right away. Can I just retrieve it from the server side using a restapi to get the apikey only if user is signed in? I'm trying to upload pictures to aws storage, but I want to store the APIKey somewhere where it's difficult to retrieve at least by hackers. Also, is there a way to send images trough the server express.js(from react native to express app) how can I do it, so I can upload it to aws storage or even if it is possible on mongodb instead of aws storage.

For example:

```
const express = require("express");
const requireAuth = require("../middlewares/requireAuth");
const router = express.Router();
router.use(requireAuth); //make sure they are signed in

/**
 * * GET: Api key for the amazon s3 bucket storage
 */
router.get("/apikey/amazonstorage", (req, res) => {
  const APIKEY = process.env.APIKEY;
  if (APIKEY) {
    res.status(200).send(APIKEY);
  } else {
    res.status(502).send(null);
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the safest way to handle API secret keys is to store them on your backend server and have the server make those requests to the third party APIs for the client (and send the results back to the client if necessary).

From the [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security):

> If you must have an API key or a secret to access some resource from your app, the most secure way to handle this would be to build an orchestration layer between your app and the resource. This could be a serverless function (e.g. using AWS Lambda or Google Cloud Functions) which can forward the request with the required API key or secret. Secrets in server side code cannot be accessed by the API consumers the same way secrets in your app code can.

Comment: I updated my question, is it like that or different?

Comment: Oh okay, nvm, so pretty much do all the process in the backend and send response back to user once is done, correct?

Comment: I wouldn't send the API itself key to the client. Just because a user is authenticated doesn't necessarily mean you want them to have access to the API key. If your 3rd party API is, for example, an S3 bucket, I think the correct course of action would be to have the server utilize the API key to fetch files and send those files to the client. The client shouldn't utilize the key directly.

Comment: Here's a link to some React Native documentation that touches on the subject: https://reactnative.dev/docs/security

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot! I will try to figure out how to send images through react native and receive it in my express app for uploading to the server. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jerry310 u found any solution?